# Create a cookie accessible to a domain A from a popup in a domain B

Tags: php, javascript

The functionality im trying to create is similar to how *facebook connect* works, in a domain A when a button is pressed a popup fires up, showing content from a domain B, on this popup if the user login a cookie is created and then the popup is closed, but since this cookie was created in the domain B i cant access that information from A. How facebook solve this? Im a javascript and PHP developer so if you provide me with a code example it will be very appreciated.

Comment: let me see if I understand what you mean. You want to have a cookie that is good for a domain other than yours or the one that it originated from?

Comment: yes, a cookie that is accessible from a domain different than the one that creates it.

Comment: There was a question about this on SO a day or so ago, and was said that it couldn't be done. Try looking for it here (SO). Pretty sure it can't be done, but then again... some can be wrong ;-)

Comment: It can't be done. Subdomains, yes. But totally different domains, no.

Comment: Sorry for the bad news amico mio. ciao e buongiorno.

Comment: Not possible it's like Microsoft wants to access Google's cookies. It will hamper security. You can create sub domain though.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies created in one domain can't be accessed from another domain.  It can be managed with subdomains, but not with different domains.  You will need to find a different solution to your issue.

I don't know what Facebook solution you are referring to, but as best I know, Facebook uses iframes on their own domain and thus they can access their own cookies from their iframe.

You can look at the [oauth spec](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31.pdf) for one standard way that authorization is done between domains.

And, here's a reference on how Facebook Connect works: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/

Comment: Well they (facebook) somehow communicates between the iframe and the parent because the site containing the facebook connect button creates a cookie after the user login right?

Comment: @DomingoSL - yes, I've given you a few references to read on how it works.